# how can i add multiple references to a blob object in a ndb model for gae

Tags: google-app-engine, blob

how can i add multiple references to a blob object in a ndb model for gae

following does not work.

```
blob_keys = blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty(repeated=True)
```

TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'repeated'

this does also not work

blob_keys=  ndb.ListProperty(blobstore.BlobKey)

Answer (score 4):

If you're using ndb, you should be using the ndb version of a blobstore reference.

```
blob_keys = ndb.BlobKeyProperty(repeated=True)
```

ListProperty isn't ndb either. Make sure you're looking at the correct documentation.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#types

Answer (score 0):

You can use a reference property:

```
class BlobInfo(db.Model):      
    reference = db.ReferenceProperty(myModel,
            collection_name='blobs', verbose_name='Title')
    primary_blob = blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty()
    secondary_blob = blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty()
```

Comment: the point was that i need to extend an existing ndb class ... dont know if it is a good idea to mix ndb and db classes ?